# How to read a file containing '[' and ']' in its name using bash command

Tags: bash, hadoop

I have a file ../reports/[2015-10-01]-[2015-10-07]. Its a large file so when I try to split it using 'split' command, I'm getting error as bash is considering [] as character class. 
My script:

```
hdfs='hadoop fs'
startDate=$1 
endDate=$2
reportPath="/reports/weeklyReport/[${startDate}]-[${endDate}]"
tmpWorkingDirectory="/tmp/weeklyReport"
filePrefix="WeeklyReport[${startDate}]-[${endDate}]-Part-"

if [ -d $tmpWorkingDirectory ]; then
    rm -rf $tmpWorkingDirectory
fi
mkdir $tmpWorkingDirectory
$hdfs -getmerge $reportPath $tmpWorkingDirectory/report.txt
split -d -C 10240000 $tmpWorkingDirectory/report.txt $filePrefix
```

.....

I'm getting error::

> getmerge: Illegal file pattern: Illegal character range near index 6
>   [2015-10-01]-[2015-10-07]

I try to use escape character '\' with '[' but it still not working.
Please suggest me how can I read this file.

Comment: It seems it is cribbing about "-". Index 6 in "[2015-10-01]-[2015-10-07]" is character "-". Probably you need to escape "-".

Comment: This is probably not a bash issue, there is nothing called "character range" in bash. There seems to be such a thing in hadoop: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)

Comment: @matz is correct. I tried creating a folder: "hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp/[2015-10-01]-[2015-10-07]". I got error: 
"mkdir: Illegal file pattern: Illegal character range near index 6". This is not a bash issue.

Comment: The hadoop documentation suggests that backslash-escaping should work. Have you tried escaping all `[` and `]`? Another _random_ guess could be to double-escape (note that this requires 3 or 4 consecutive backslashes in a `"`-string in bash).

Comment: Thanks @matz and Manjunath but nothing seems to work. I tried to escape brackets but It still not working but giving some other error:
Illegal file pattern: Unclosed character class near index 11
[2015-10-01
                   ^

Comment: In addition to the hadoop problem, you should (almost) always put shell variable references in double-quotes, to keep the shell from parsing them weirdly. Examples: `if [ -d "$tmpWorkingDirectory" ]; then` and `split -d -C 10240000 "$tmpWorkingDirectory/report.txt" "$filePrefix"`. Unfortunately, you can't do this with `$hdfs` because it needs to be split into multiple words -- the proper ways to do things like this are to use an function or array (see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).

Answer (score 0):

... and what about this? `$hdfs -getmerge "$reportPath" "$tmpWorkingDirectory/report.txt"`